# How to capture stdout/log output of an agent in SLIME?

Tags: clojure, slime, swank

I send a task to an agent, but can't see the output of any print statements I've put into the function. How do I trace code execution on agents?

**EDIT:** Turns out I *do* get the output in the console, but not in SLIME. The question now is, how to see the output in SLIME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to start swank from emacs as the inferior lisp process instead of calling lein swank from the shell.  One way to do this is to use [elein](https://github.com/remvee/elein/blob/master/elein.el) (the command is `M-x elein-swank`). Then you can either inspect the output in the inferior lisp buffer (which is called `*elein-swank*` in the example of using elein), or execute `slime-redirect-inferior-output` and have the output inline in the repl.  Clojure.contrib.logging is a useful tool for sending log output.

Comment: In more recent versions of clojure-mode, you can do `M-x clojure-jack-in` to start SLIME and Clojure with STDOUT appearing in the REPL.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the calls in your repl in `(with-out-str (def result (my-code)))` to capture the output as a string. this way you can do it for just the code you're working on and you dont have to restart your repl to start getting your output.